# Is it necessary to use `relationship()` in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've noticed that many SQLAlchemy tutorials would use `relationship()` in "connecting" multiple tables together, may their relationship be one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many. However, when using raw SQL, you are not able to define the relationships between tables **explicitly**, as far as I know.

In what cases is `relationship()` required and not required? Why do we have to explicitly define the relationship between tables in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SQL, **tables** are related to each other via **foreign keys**. In an ORM, **models** are related to each other via **relationships**. You're not required to use relationships, just as you are not required to use models (i.e. the ORM). Mapped classes give you the ability to work with tables *as if they are objects* in memory; along the same lines, relationships give you the ability to work with foreign keys *as if they are references* in memory.

You want to set up relationships for the same purpose as wanting to set up models: convenience. For this reason, the two go hand-in-hand. It is uncommon to see models with raw foreign keys but no relationships.